# jaydata include & order

Tags: javascript, filter, jaydata

I am calling a table using JayData, and including a few other tables, which if you are not familiar with JayData, is basically just a join.

My code looks like this:

```
db.Table1.include("Table2").include("Table3").toArray();
```

My problem is I want to order the data by a field in `Table3`, but applying the `.order` to the call like so...

```
db.Table1.include("Table2").include("Table3").order("FieldName").toArray();
```

...causes the code to break saying that there is no such fieldname on table1. The order filter is defaulting to `Table1`, but I want to order from a field in `Table3`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.Table1.include("Table2").include("Table3").orderBy("it.Table1Field.Table3FieldName").toArray();
```

Comment: whenever i do this i get an error saying "it" is not a parameter of Table1.

Comment: I am going to assume there is no way to do that without using some kind of function within the orderBy. I found a work around for it just by seperating the queries, and it actually is better performance wise. i grab the id from table1 and then queyr table2 and 3 on that id.